# problem changing to simple fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm following the book practical algebra a self teaching guide but can't understand this exercise  could someone please explain it to me

change to a simple fraction:

$$\frac{{\dfrac{1}a}+1}{\dfrac{1}{a^2}-1}$$

the answer should be:

$\dfrac{a}{1-a}$

Comment: For $\dfrac{{\frac{1}a}+1}{\frac{1}{a^2}-1}$, multiply top and bottom by $a^2$, factor and simplify

Comment: using $a^2$ i can get to the answer but the original exercise was a2 as i wrote it in the question, is it ok to do that kind of change ? 

thanks

Comment: What does $a2$ mean?

Comment: I thought it was the same as 2a,  look at a screenshot of the book [link](http://imgur.com/he1U9gh), exercise 40.

thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a four story fraction, first consider separately the numerator and the denominator:
$$
N=\frac{1}{a}+1,
\qquad
D=\frac{1}{a^2}-1
$$
Now, let's work out $N$:
$$
N=\frac{1+a}{a}
$$
which cannot be simplified further. For $D$ we have
$$
D=\frac{1}{a^2}-1=\frac{1-a^2}{a^2}=\frac{(1-a)(1+a)}{a^2}
$$
Finally, your initial fraction is
$$
N\cdot D^{-1}=\frac{1+a}{a}\frac{a^2}{(1-a)(1+a)}=\frac{a}{1-a}
$$

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I got stuck because of the typo in the book but is always nice to see everything step by step :)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the answer in the book, there is a typographical error in the statement of the problem, which should read $$\frac{\frac{1}{a} + 1}{\frac{1}{a^2} - 1}$$  As Henry indicated in the comments, you must multiply the numerator and denominator by $a^2$, factor the numerator, then cancel to obtain the answer $$\frac{a}{1 - a}$$